# How do I drop variables before and after a dummy variable that captures a behavior switches from 1 to 0

Tags: r, date, subset

I am dealing with two data frames that give me two different sets of information. I have one variable in one of the data frame that equals 1 when a certain event is taking place and 0 when the event is not taking place. I want to match the data frame only on the 0s and the first 1 that appears before switching to 0 and after the event begins taking place again. There are multiple unique ids that this occurs for.

df1 is an example of what I'm starting with. df2 is an example of what I'm hoping the output will look like.

```
df1
index   ID      date        event
1       11      12/2/2009   1
2       11      12/2/2009   1
3       11      12/2/2009   1
4       11      12/3/2009   0
5       11      12/3/2009   0
6       11      12/3/2009   0
7       11      12/4/2009   0
8       11      12/4/2009   1
9       11      12/4/2009   1
10      11      12/4/2009   1
11      11      12/4/2009   1
12      12      12/1/2009   1
13      12      12/2/2009   1
14      12      12/2/2009   0
15      12      12/2/2009   0
16      12      12/2/2009   1
17      12      12/2/2009   1
18      12      12/2/2009   1


df2

index   ID      date        event
3       11      12/2/2009   1
4       11      12/3/2009   0
5       11      12/3/2009   0
6       11      12/3/2009   0
7       11      12/4/2009   0
8       11      12/4/2009   1
13      12      12/2/2009   1
14      12      12/2/2009   0
15      12      12/2/2009   0
16      12      12/2/2009   1
```

I've included the index numbers just for illustrative purposes. The dataset is way too large for me to individually pick out these observations.

Would appreciate any tips on where to start!

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

df1 <- data.table(df1)
df2 <- data.table(df2)

df1[, accept := event == 0 | cumsum(event) == 1, ID]
df2[, accept := event == 0 | cumsum(event) == 1, ID]

merged <- merge(df1, df2.....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to select the rows for one `ID` and apply the function for each `ID`.

```
select_rows <- function(x) {
  tmp <- rle(x == 1)
  ind1 <- tmp$lengths[which.max(tmp$values)]
  ind2 <- which.max(cumsum(tmp$values) == 2) - 1
  ind1:(sum(tmp$lengths[1:ind2]) + 1)
}

library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% slice(select_rows(event))

#   index    ID date      event
#   <int> <int> <chr>     <int>
# 1     3    11 12/2/2009     1
# 2     4    11 12/3/2009     0
# 3     5    11 12/3/2009     0
# 4     6    11 12/3/2009     0
# 5     7    11 12/4/2009     0
# 6     8    11 12/4/2009     1
# 7    13    12 12/2/2009     1
# 8    14    12 12/2/2009     0
# 9    15    12 12/2/2009     0
#10    16    12 12/2/2009     1
```

`select_rows` returns row numbers that are to be selected in each `ID`. So for `ID = 11` it returns `3:8` so these rows are selected using `slice`.